# Using Iterable with scala generics

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections, scalaz

I have two functions with the exact same implementation - only one handles `Option` and the other handles `Seq`. I'd like to use generics to write this as a single function that handles `Iterable`, while keeping the concrete type in the calling code - if this is possible?

`def f[T](a: Seq[Failure \/ T]): Failure \/ Seq[T] = { ??? }`
`def g[T](b: Option[Failure \/ T]): Failure \/ Option[T] = { ??? }`

The implementation isn't important, but for context they translate from a collection of results (each of which may either have succeeded (`T`) or failed (`Failure`)) to either a single failure or a complete collection of successful results. `\/` is just scalaz's version of Either.

I'm looking to do something like this:
`def f[I[T] <: Iterable[T]](results: I[Failure \/ T]): Failure \/ I[T] = { ??? }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head and not tested, so apologies for typos.

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

def combine[M[X] <: Iterable[X], T](
  input: M[Failure \/ T]
)(
  implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, M[T]]
): Failure \/ M[T] = {
   def inner(builder: Builder[T, M[T]], els: M[T]): Failure \/ M[T] = {
     els.headOption match {
       case Some(\/-(right)) => inner(builder += right, els.tail)
       case Some(-\/(left)) => -\/(left)
       case None => \/-(builder.result())
     }
   }
   inner(cbf(), input)
}
```

Something like that, you have an inner recursion that "short circuits" when the first failure is found.

Answer (score 3):

In FP, this pattern is expressed by an interplay between a [*traversable*](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala) collection (such as `Seq` or `Option`) and an [*applicative*](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala) functor (such as `Failure \/ ?`).

The generic implementation (using `scalaz`) is then

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

def f[F[_]: Traverse, G[_]: Applicative, T](a: F[G[T]]): G[F[T]] = a.sequence
```

At the call site, you would do

```
import scalaz.std._

type FailureOr[A] = Failure \/ A

val x: Option[FailureOr[Int]] = ???
val y: List[FailureOr[Int]] = ???
val z: Vector[FailureOr[Int]] = ???

f[Option, FailureOr, Int](x)
f[List, FailureOr, Int](y)
f[Vector, FailureOr, Int](z)

// or just directly

import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

x.sequence
y.sequence
z.sequence
```

Note that I used `List` and `Vector` instead of `Seq`. This is because `scalaz` doesn't provide an implicit `Traverse` instance for `Seq`. While conceptually `Seq` is traversable, it is better (for performance reasons) to implement the `Traverse` operations specifically for concrete implementations of `Seq` such as `List` or `Vector`. If you really want to, you can write your own instance of `Traverse[Seq]`, just know that it will be suboptimal for some implementations of `Seq`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (see implementation for `Future.sequence` as an example):

```
def f[T, M[X] <: Iterable[X]](results: M[Failure \/ T): Failure \/ M[T]
```

You'll probably need some `CanBuildFrom` too.